# How to pass an anonymous enumerated type into a subroutine?

Tags: delphi, enums, subroutine, delphi-10-seattle

I'm trying to make a convenient function to convert a `System.Classes.TShiftState` into a user-readable string. To make it easier, I've made a subroutine to perform common code, to make the function more compact.

The problem is, I cannot figure out how to pass one of the `TShiftState` enum types into this subroutine. I tried `Byte`, `Integer`, and `Cardinal` but I keep getting `Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'Enumeration'` (or whichever type I was trying). Hovering over one of them only shows `$1` where the type would usually be.

```
function ShiftStateStr(const Shift: TShiftState): String;
  procedure A(const Sh: Byte; const Str: String);
  begin
    if Sh in Shift then
      Result:= Result + StrLen(Str, Length(Str)+1)
    else
      Result:= Result + StrLen('', Length(Str)+1);
  end;
begin
  Result:= '';
  A(ssShift, 'Shift');
  A(ssAlt, 'Alt');
  A(ssCtrl, 'Ctrl');
  A(ssLeft, 'Left');
  A(ssRight, 'Right');
  A(ssMiddle, 'Middle');
  A(ssDouble, 'Double');
  A(ssTouch, 'Touch');
  A(ssPen, 'Pen');
  A(ssCommand, 'Cmd');
  A(System.Classes.ssHorizontal, 'Horz');
end;
```

> NOTE: `StrLen` is a separate function which pads a string with spaces of a given length.

`TShiftState` is defined in `System.Classes` like so:

```
type
  TShiftState = set of (ssShift, ssAlt, ssCtrl,
    ssLeft, ssRight, ssMiddle, ssDouble, ssTouch, ssPen, ssCommand, ssHorizontal);
```

How can I properly pass this into the `A` subroutine?

Comment: You have been caught out by the pool decision of Emba not to name the enumerated type. This is a perfect example of why enumerated types should always be named.

Comment: Also `StrLen` is a name used for a function that returns the length of a null terminated character array. Use `str.PadLeft(n)` instead.

Comment: Why not use built in functions to do this? https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/using-generics-rtti-to-get-enum-string-name-or-enum-value

Comment: @John Because I want the strings to be shortened, and not have `ss` in front of them. Like I said, more human-readable :P

Comment: @David Thanks for pointing that out, actually this function can pad left, right, or center, and can use desired character instead of a space.

Comment: All the same StrLen is a weak name

Comment: @JerryDodge you can copy the string minus the first two characters. The problem with your approach is if you change your set, you need to change your function later on.

Comment: @John Well if *Emba* wants to change the set. If it were my own, I wouldn't have a problem :D But `Command` is shortened to `Cmd`, and `Horizontal` to `Horz`, etc.

Comment: @John What would you pass to `TypeInfo()`? There is no named type for the values that make up the `TShiftState` set. The enumeration is anonymous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change first parameter of `A` to `const Sh: TShiftState`. Then change each call to A into the form

```
A([ssShift], 'Shift');
```

and finally the condition test into

```
if Sh <= Shift then
```

Ref. [Expressions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29)

> X <= Y is True just in case every member of X is a member of Y